# Solving given homogoneous systems.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

It is given that 
$ A =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$ and $ \vec{x} =
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$.

It is then asked that the homogeneous system $(A-I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ be solved and that this result be used to solve $A\vec{x} = \vec{x}$ for $ \vec{x} =
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$ and $A\vec{x}=-2\vec{x}$.

---

I'm not really certain what exactly is going on here, but:

I begin $(A-I)\vec{x}=\vec{0} \implies A\vec{x}-I\vec{x}=\vec{0} \implies A\vec{x} = I\vec{x} \implies A\vec{x}=\vec{x}$ which can only be true if $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ or $A=I$, but indeed we are given $A \neq I \implies \vec{x}=\vec{0}$.

---

I don't know how terribly helpful this is, or, at least it seems so trivial that it must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that your conclusion is flawed.

From $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}$, it is not possible to conclude that either $A=I$ or $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. In fact, the vectors satisfying this property, or more generally $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$, are called *eigenvectors* with *eigenvalue* $\lambda$. As an example, you may check that $\mathbf{v}=[1,2]^T$ is an eigenvector of
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6&-2\\
0&2
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
In the given exercise you are probably supposed to realize that solving $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}$ is equivalent to solving $(A-I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. The solutions are the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$.

How may we use this idea to solve $A\mathbf{x}=-2\mathbf{x}$? Are the solutions eigenvectors? If yes, what is the eigenvalue?

> Solve $(A+2I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ instead. The solutions are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-2$.